# Persistent Auth Token Expires

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, appharbor

I have an ASP.NET MVC application using forms authentication.  Here's the line of code where I create the auth token:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
```

My web.config contains:

```
<system.web>
  <machineKey validationKey="{unique key}" decryptionKey="{unique key}" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/account/" timeout="2880" />
  </authentication>
  ...
</system.web>
<location path="my">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Despite the parameter for the persistent cookie being set to true, my users get logged out after a few days of inactivity.

The app is deployed to AppHarbor, but I experienced the same behavior when it was hosted on a dedicated server.

What am I missing that would cause users to get logged out sporadically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your timeout is set to 2880 minutes, which is 48 hours?

> **timeout** is used to specify a limited lifetime for the forms authentication session. The default value is 30 minutes. If a persistent forms authentication cookie is issued, the timeout attribute is also used to set the lifetime of the persistent cookie.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx

Comment: Ah, I see that in ASP.NET 1.1, the timeout was ignored for persistent cookies, but starting in 2.0, it's used for persistent cookies too.  Duh.

Comment: I am changing the timeout to 5259600 (60 minutes/hour * 24  hours/day * 365.25 days/year * 10 years).

Comment: Are you sure that's long enough?

Comment: Given that (by default) session state is stored in memory on the server side, will this not possibly adversely affect the performance of the web application? I see what Jeff's trying to achieve (persisted login on client) and Im wondering if storing my own persisted login user "token" might be a better solution? Would prefer not to re-invent the wheel though :)